# SDL crashes application?

Tags: c++, sdl

Hey so I am still getting a grip on C++ in general but I wanted to try implementing some better graphics into my game here using SDL. My issue is that it is closing my program when it should be staying open and running functions in the background..

I really have no idea why it is doing this and I know I linked my lib's correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include <SDL/SDL_opengl.h>

#define HEIGHT 25
#define WIDTH 80
using namespace std;

void makeBoard();
void buildBoard();
void nextStep();
void makeCell();
void setcolor(unsigned short color)  ;

///GLOBALS
int state;
time_t seconds;
int board[HEIGHT][WIDTH] = {0};
int ghostBoard[HEIGHT][WIDTH] = {0};
bool inGame = true;
int seed = 0;
/*
The different color codes are

0   BLACK
1   BLUE
2   GREEN
3   CYAN
4   RED
5   MAGENTA
6   BROWN
7   LIGHTGRAY
8   DARKGRAY
9   LIGHTBLUE
10  LIGHTGREEN
11  LIGHTCYAN
12  LIGHTRED
13  LIGHTMAGENTA
14  YELLOW
15  WHITE
*/

struct Cell //Brick structures which holds 4 elements
{
    //Elements are used for x and y position of the brick and its width and height
    float width;
    float height;
};

int main(int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //initialize SDL
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    //Set OpenGL memory usage
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );

    //Caption of the window
    SDL_WM_SetCaption( "Our first game", NULL );

    //Size of the window
    SDL_SetVideoMode(600,400,32, SDL_OPENGL );

    //Specific the clear color
    glClearColor(1,1,1,1); //RED,GREEN,BLUE,ALPHA

    //What portion of the screen we will display
    glViewport(0,0,600,400);

    //Shader model - Use this
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    //2D rendering
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    //"Save" it
    glLoadIdentity();

    //Disable depth checking
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    std::cout << "OpenGL is running\n";
    std::cout << "Main loop has started\n";

    //Handles the main loop
    bool isRunning = true;

    //For handling with event
    SDL_Event event;

    float width = 80; //width of the rectangle
    float height = 20; //height of the rectangle


    //Main game loop
    while ( isRunning )
    {
        //EVENTS
        while ( SDL_PollEvent(&event) )
        {
            //if the window was closed
            if ( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
            {
                isRunning = false;
            }

            //If a button was released and the button is escape
            if ( event.type == SDL_KEYUP && event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE )
            {
                isRunning = false;
            }

            if ( event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_r )
            {
                glClearColor(1,0,0,1);
            }

            if ( event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN ) //Check for presed down buttons
            {

            }

            else if ( event.type == SDL_KEYUP ) //Checking for released buttons
            {

            }

            //logic that should happen for a certain event
            makeBoard();
            nextStep();
        }

        //RENDERING to the screen
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glPushMatrix(); //Start rendering phase

        glOrtho(0,600,400,0,-1,1); //Set the matrix

        glColor4ub(0,0,0,255); //Black color

        glColor4ub(255,0,0,255); //Red color

        glColor4ub(0,0,255,255); //Blue color

        glBegin(GL_QUADS); //Render the bricks

        glEnd(); //End drawing

        glPopMatrix(); //End rendering phase

        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();

        SDL_Delay(1); //Delay / pause
    }

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}


void makeBoard()
{
    seconds = time (NULL);
    seed = seconds;
    srand(seed);
    /* Seed the random number generator with the specified seed */

    for(int y = 0; y < 25; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 80; x++)
        {
            /* 50% chance for a cell to be alive */
            //cout << "board["<<x<<"]["<<y<<"] == "<< board[x][y]<<endl;
            if(rand() % 100 < 35)
            {
                board[x][y] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                board[x][y] = 0;
            }
            if(board[x][y] == 1)
            {
                cout << char(2);
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }
            /*if(y == 20 & x == 10){
               cout << "(";

            }else{
            cout << ".";
            }*/
            //this is just printing out the current location it is iterating through.
            //9cout << "X: " << x << " Y: " << y << endl;

        }
        //cout << endl;
        //cout << "================================================================================";
        //cout << endl;
    }


}
void buildBoard()
{
    for(int y = 0; y < 25; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 80; x++)
        {
            board[x][y] = 0;
            if(ghostBoard[x][y] == 1)
            {
                board[x][y] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                board[x][y] = 0;
            }
            if(board[x][y] == 1)
            {
                setcolor(10);
                cout << char(2);
            }
            else
            {
                setcolor(2);
                cout << " ";
            }

        }
        //cout << endl;
        //cout << "================================================================================";
        //cout << endl;
    }
    cin.get();
    nextStep();
}

void nextStep()
{


    for(int y = 0; y < 25; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 80; x++)
        {
            //cout << "board[" << x << "]" << "[" << y << "]" << endl;
            //if(board[(x-1)][(y-1)] == 1) cout << "WOOOOOT";
            state = 0;
            state = board[(x)][(y-1)] + state; // top - middle
            state = board[(x-1)][(y-1)] + state; //top - left
            state = board[(x+1)][(y-1)] + state; //top - right
            state = board[(x)][(y+1)] + state; //bottom - middle
            state = board[(x-1)][(y+1)] + state; //bottom - left
            state = board[(x+1)][(y+1)] + state; //bottom - right
            state = board[(x-1)][(y)] + state; //middle - left
            state = board[(x+1)][(y)] + state; //middle - right
            //cout << "state: " << state << " board[" << x << "][" << y << "]" << endl;
            if(state == 3) ghostBoard[x][y] = 1;
            if(state < 2) ghostBoard[x][y] = 0 ;
            //if(board[x][y] == 1){
            //if(state == 2) ghostBoard[x][y] = 1;
            //}else{
            //ghostBoard[x][y] = 0;
            //}
            if(state > 3) ghostBoard[x][y] = 0;
            state = 0;
        }
        //cout << endl;
        //cout << "================================================================================";
        //cout << endl;
    }
    //cout << endl;
    //cout << seconds << endl;
    buildBoard();
}

void setcolor(unsigned short color)                 //The function that you'll use to
{
    //set the colour
    HANDLE hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hcon,color);
}

void makeCell()
{
    glClearColor(0,0,1,1);
}
```

Comment: When is the program closing? When you minimise it?

Comment: Did you try running in a debugger to determine which code path it's taking to exit?

Comment: Have you determined whether it's crashing or exiting normally?

Comment: I recall that SDL dumps output into text files in the program directory. Check stdout.txt and stderr.txt if they're present.

Comment: I get this in my output file:
OpenGL is running
Main loop has started

Also I get a bunch of symbols that look kinda like this [] trying to display a character I think. Just a heads up, it is infact crashing and not "exiting".

Answer (score 4):

From looking at your code there are a couple of problem areas. The major one that's pervasive in several functions is that you've switched `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` when iterating through the `board`. You end up accessing an out-of-bound index.

The other issue is that `nextStep` and `buildBoard` recursively call each other with no exit condition. The result is an eventual stack overflow and a crashing program.

You're also calling `srand()` more than once during the execution lifetime of your program. You'll get less than random values as a result. It's a minor issue that's easy to fix.

There are probably other problems still lurking about but fixing the above outlined should get you on your way.